# Placing elements on top of flash video in wmode:window

Tags: flash, youtube, z-index

I've looked all around for a solution to layering elements on top of youtube videos in wmode "window". I realize the fix is to use "opaque" or "transparent" but this causes choppy playback using both methods for slower computers so that's not really a fix for people who have websites centered around videos. I've tried setting the z-index and position of both the iframe and the menu for example but that doesn't change anything. I have the iframe set to 200 and the menu set to 10000000 and that changes nothing. So is there any trick to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, no. You have to use a `wmode` to pull off this effect, and using the `wmode` is more intensive on the CPU.